# rotate as wheel using animate css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to rotate the list using animate.css I have 5 list item.I'm keeping 1st and last list item(0 and 4) constant and rotate the list item(1,2,3) I want to roate the list item with animation.I want to rotate as wheel.I have tried with next button click.It's not animated as expected

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");

var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
//var FirstLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(1)","li:nth-child(3)").addClass('animated flipInY');
var thirdLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(3)").addClass('animated fadeInRight');

var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)").addClass('animated fadeInRight');
  $(secondLi).before(fourthLi);
  });

 });
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
   $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```css
ul{
list-style-type:none;
width:500px;
border:1px solid red;
}
ul li{
width:50px;
display:inline;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li> 1</li>
  <li >2</li>
  <li > 3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>

<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```

Comment: Why do you want the first and last child of the ul to remain in the same place? Do they have to be a part of the list? Or do they have other functionality from the rest of the list?

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('.flex-next').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
   var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");

var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
//var FirstLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(1)","li:nth-child(3)").addClass('animated flipInY');
var thirdLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(3)").addClass('animated rotateIn');

var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)").addClass('animated rotateIn');
  $(secondLi).before(fourthLi);
  });

 });
$('.flex-prev').click(function(){
  $('.thumbnailIcon').each(function(index, item){
    var fourthLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(2)");
    var secondLi = $(item).find("li:nth-child(4)");
   $(secondLi).after(fourthLi);
  });

 });

});
```

```css
ul{
list-style-type:none;
width:500px;
border:1px solid red;
}
ul li{
width:50px;
height: 50px;
display: inline-flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css">
</head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parent flex-active-slider">
<div class="node_id"><span>233</span></div>
<ul class="thumbnailIcon">
  <li>left 0</li>  
  <li> 1</li>
  <li >2</li>
  <li > 3</li>
  <li>right 4</li>  
</ul> 
</li>

<a  class="flex-prev">prev<a>
<a  class="flex-next">next<a>
```

Comment: ul li{
display:inline-block;
}

Comment: I want to rotate as wheel

Comment: @grinmax Please elaborate on what you changed, how and why. This post isn't helping somebody understand the solution, it just offers it without any information. Try being constructive and passing your knowledge on, not just solve problems.

Comment: @user3386779 look now my snippet